# To leave in the list items whose values coincide with the numbers of their positions in the list

Tags: list, haskell

I need to change list for example:

`[1,2,4,6,5,10]`

To this one

`[1,2,5]` (the list of elements that are on correct position).

1. 1st element value is 1 - ok,
2. element value is 2 - ok,
3. 3rd element value is 4 but expected 3 (due to the index)- remove

and etc. How can I solve the error which is attached below?

My code:

```
module Count where
import Control.Monad.State

nthel n xs = last xsxs
    where xsxs = take n xs

 deleteNth i items = take i items ++ drop (1 + i) items

 repeatNTimes 0 _ = return ()
 repeatNTimes n xs =
   do
     if (n == nthel n xs) then return()
       else deleteNth (n-1) xs
         repeatNTimes (n-1) xs

 list = [1,2,3,4,5]
 main = repeatNTimes (length list) list
```

I have the following error:

```
 * Couldn't match type `Int' with `()'
       Expected type: [()]
       Actual type: [Int]
* In the expression: deleteNth (n - 2) xs
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    if (n == nthel n xs) then return () else deleteNth (n - 2) xs
  In the expression:
    do { if (n == nthel n xs) then return () else deleteNth (n - 2) xs;
         repeatNTimes (n - 1) xs }
```

Comment: Could you please provide code for what you have tried?

Comment: Keep a counter, using an auxiliar function, and move through the list using recursion? Use some of the indexing lists functions in `Data.List`? Write something even if close to pseudo code

Comment: Your error does not match the code you wrote...

Answer (score 2):

A really nice way to work with this is to stitch functions together. First one might need to get to know the functions in the `Data.List` module, which you can find with hoogle: http://hoogle.haskell.org

**Data.List Module functions**

I'll give you a little bit of a boost here. The functions I would pick out are the `zip` function: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:zip whose type is `[a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]` and then the `filter` function https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter whose type is `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` and then the `map` function whose type is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` along with the `fst :: (a, b) -> a`

**Function Composition**

These functions can be stitched together using the function composition operator: `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` it takes two functions that share a common input/output point (in the type signature they are the second and first parameters, respectively; `a -> b` and `b -> c`) and it will then join them into one single function.

**Stacking it up - required knowledge**

In order to do what you want to do, you really need to know about simple types, parameterised types, ranges (including lazy infinite ranges would help), functions and possibly recursion as well some higher order functions and how Haskell functions are curried, and to understand function composition. It wouldn't hurt to add a basic understanding of what typeclasses do and are into the mix.

I helped author a tutorial which can really help with understanding how this stuff works from a usage point of view by following a series of interesting examples. It's not too long, and you might find it much easier to approach your problem once you have understood some of the more foundational stuff: http://happylearnhaskelltutorial.com — note that it's not tuned to teaching you how to construct stuff, that'll be coming in a later volume, but it should give you enough understanding to be able to at least guess at an answer, or understand the one below.

**The Answer - spoilers**

If you want to work this out yourself, you should stop here and come back later on when you're feeling more confident. However, I'm going to put one possible answer just below, so don't look if you don't want to know yet!

```
positionals :: (Enum a, Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> [a]
positionals = map fst . filter (\(x, y) -> x == y) . zip [1..]
```

Keep in mind this is only one way of doing this. There are simpler more explanatory ways to do it, and while it might possibly seem inefficient, Haskell has **list/stream fusion** which compiles that function into something that will do a single pass across your data.